# document.getElementById can't find an element

Tags: javascript, opera

Trying to eliminate the annoying default autoplay feature on Site-Which-Must-Not-Be-Named I made a custom JavaScript for Opera 12.17 (Presto):

```
setInterval(function(){
    var ap = document.getElementById('autoplay-checkbox');
    if ((ap) && (ap.checked === true)) ap.click();
},
500);
```

`setInterval` is here because I do not want to deal with `window.load` and similar handlers and I am not sure about the moment when the checkbox is being created and initialized.

The script worked for a very long period of time, but now, after I turned Opera cookies off for Site-Which-Must-Not-Be-Named, `getElementById` returns `null` according to `console.log`. It simply cannot find the checkbox, although when executing

```
var ap = document.getElementById('autoplay-checkbox');
ap.click();
```

in DragonFly console, it works well. I turned cookies on, and again - JS cannot find the checkbox.

What is happening?

**Update**

I am completely lost in doubt: the script works on some content pages, especially when loaded by direct links, but doesn't work on other pages (with equal layout).

Comment: The "site which must not be named" - is this a well-known domain or your own?  I feel that a large part of this question depends on whether that site is removing the box from the document or not.

Comment: and have you tried window.onload ?

Comment: That box may be in an iframe, might be removed from the DOM, might have its ID updated post-load, a lot of things could be happening. Need more info.

Comment: @Steve: a well-known one. I am afraid that if they find my "hack", they could invent something smarter.

Comment: @webduvet: `and have you tried window.onload?` Of course!

Comment: `might have its ID updated post-load`. setInterval should handle this.

Comment: These commands are working in Chrome. Have you tried increasing the interval, just for the sake of extra dummy testing?

Comment: PS: Upvoted for *Site-Which-Must-Not-Be-Named*

Comment: You know that `(ap.checked === true)` is the same as `ap.checked`, right?

Comment: @Bruno Toffolo: They worked in Opera 30 minutes ago and work now when copy-pasted into console. P.S. The custom script is being loaded and executed.

Comment: In the console: Do you see the id? Is there an iframe in play?